# How to retrieve the facebook oauth 2.0 access_token

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am trying to get the access_token of the logged in facebook user.

I get something like this.. url followed by the code i am retrieve the code..

it says in the guide to exchange it for access_token...

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&
    redirect_uri=http://www.my-site.com/&
    client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&
    code=2.hJFWoMlLf3tLOSos_qNCBg__.3600.1279836000-10000100XXXXXXX|kGwPB4y5K_-ijD9_1CfjSpT-oaY..

How i can exchange it for a access_token using what FB.api or jquery or javascript..

When i plug this url in the address bar.. i am able to see access_token..

I appreciate if somebody can tell me how to retrieve the access_token using javascript or jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to Facebook, and my personal experiences with the api, the `FB.getSession()` function is deprecated and should throw an exception if called.

From facebook:

> The FB.getAuthResponse method is a replacement for the FB.getSession method which was deprecated after the migration to OAuth 2.0.

Instead you should use the getLoginStatus callback -

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
});

//Example structure of response object
var eg =
{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
};
```

source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the JavaScript SDK, then after logging in the user, getting the access token in your JavaScript code is as simple as:

```
FB.getSession().access_token
```

However, `getSession` may return `null` if a user is logged out, so the proper way is to first  check for null before accessing the token.

```
var session = FB.getSession();
if(session != null) { // user is still logged in
    console.log(session.access_token);
}
```